# AJAX Post not sending form data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have the following `AJAX POST` below, for some reason looking at my logging (server side) the request it's sending is is blank `{}` not JSON data is sent. I have exhausted all possible  server side issues this is a client side issue with the script not sending data. why?

bootstrap-wizard.js found here -> [GitHub](https://github.com/OrcaSystems/bootstrap-application-wizard/commit/a64498b7b19a950490c49b9f04d9841c92893b54)

**My page code overrides the script submit:**

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-wizard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {

       var options = {width:1000};
       var wizard = $("#some-wizard").wizard(options);

        $("#open-wizard").click(function() {
        wizard.show();
    });


wizard.on("submit", function(wizard) {

        $.ajax({
                  url: '/api/v1/rewards/campaigns/',
                  type: 'POST',
                  contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                  data: $('#wizard').serialize(),
                  beforeSend: function (request) {

                      request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val());
                  },

                  success: function(data, textStatus) {
                        wizard.submitSuccess(); // displays the success card
                        wizard.hideButtons(); // hides the next and back buttons
                        wizard.updateProgressBar(0); // sets the progress meter to 0

                      console.log('success');

                  },
                  error: function(errorThrown){
                     // data = JSON.parse(errorThrown.responseText);

                       wizard.submitError(); // display the error card
                       wizard.hideButtons(); // hides the next and back buttons


                      console.log(errorThrown);
                  }
              });



  });



   });



</script>
```

**This is my form:**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="wizard" enctype="application/json" >
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="wizard" id="some-wizard">
   <h1>{% trans "Setup Wizard" %}</h1>


   <div class="wizard-card" data-cardname="card1">
      <h3>{% trans "General" %}</h3>

       etc, etc <=== all my form fields here

   </div>
```

Comment: inclose your javascript in a `<script>` tag

Comment: have you tried to `console.log($('#wizard').serialize())` before the ajax request? does it contain the correct data?

Comment: @tborychowski the only thing outputs is csrfmiddlewaretoken=kr5Ixi1T62E9hhoUNabC1dAYvVXs5WeR no other data for the fields tho

Comment: Your Javascript variable `wizard` is a reference to the DIV not the form. So there is no `submit` for the `wizard` element. I cannot imagine that the $.ajax would be called at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) returns key/value formatted URL encoded data (x-www-form-urlencoded), not JSON. If your server side requires JSON then you need to change your data parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : JSON.stringify({ input_a : 'value a', input_b : 'value b' }),
    ...
});
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery) for how to convert a form into JSON automatically.

Comment: I see, in the script example they always just use  data: $('#wizard').serialize() what you suggested works, but I'm a little confused

Comment: Well `$('#wizard').serialize()` is valid if your server side is expecting x-www-form-urlencoded data, but not if it's expecting JSON.

Comment: This is a common ambiguity with the acronym JSON. Generally, it specifies the way a literal object is written in Javascript. Today it mostly refers to the "string representation of a literal Javascript object". The former has no wrapping quotes whereas the second has ... `{...}` and `"{...}"`

Comment: @devnull69 `JSON` is and was `JavaScript Object Notation` (a string representation of an object) and I don't recall that the meaning has changed recently? What do you mean by "today ... mostly"?

Comment: Are you sure that underscores work in object literal keys? My guess is that you need to wrap them in `''`/`""`

Comment: I mean that JSON originally means "the way Javascript represents object literals". It is NOT a string representation of an object, it is the object representation in the Javascript source code. If you STRINGIFY this object, you will get a JSON string, which is the string representation of the object literal that was originally written using JSON

Comment: btw ... this is what "ambiguous" means :-)