# $.ajax post doesn't post data (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, post

I can't figure out why this problem is arising. When I make an ajax post request in my javascript file, the url gets called, but the data wont get sent. Here's how I make a post request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {test: "test"},
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

    });
</script>
```

And on my backend, here's the post method I'm using:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); // returns {}
  console.log(req.params); // returns {}
});
```

Here's what I tried so far: [XMLHttpRequest to Post HTML Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592679/xmlhttprequest-to-post-html-form), [AJAX Post not sending form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538940/ajax-post-not-sending-form-data) , [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest) but unfortunately none of them worked for me.

Comment: you can remove the contentType option, that's not necessary for what you're doing. (the default will suffice)

Comment: You're sure you're hitting your endpoint? You're seeing stuff in your console on the server-side whenever you send an AJAX request? Have you tried doing `console.log(req)` to see if the data is on a different property?

Comment: try `JSON.stringify({test: "test"})`

Comment: @KevinB I've tried it without contentType too, still doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: you have to send some response to FE right? `res.send('something')` ?? otherwise that request will get timedout in browser

Comment: Besides MikeC's advice, do you have something parsing the body? bodyparser maybe?

Comment: @MikeC Yes, the server side is being called and I am seeing {} on the server side console.

Comment: @Mendax I tried JSON.stringify({test: "test"}), still not working

Comment: @rie `dataType: "json" sends data in JSON` eh, no, that's not what dataType does.

Comment: @rie Wow, that worked! I'mm definitely sure I tried application/json before changing it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Somehow it's working now! If you post this as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: Why would you want to use Ajax request when you can actually post it directly using `"action"`attribute?

Comment: @BabakRz Thanks! I`ve post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataType: "json"` expects data in JSON, but `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` sends data in different way. Maybe you should write `dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json"` or `dataType: "html", contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`?